# Laravel model getting instances of the class

Tags: model, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing a package in the workbench environment. I have a model like

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Webshop\Models;

use Vendor\Webshop\Models\Country as Country;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

/**
 * A catalog
 */
class Catalog extends Eloquent {

    // Define the database
    protected $table = 'catalogs';

    // Mass assignment restriction
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    // Return the countries related to this catalog
    public function countries() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Vendor\Webshop\Models\Country');
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether to enforce the compability check or not
     */
    public function getForceCompabilityTest() {
        return $this->force_compability_check;
    }

}

?>
```

I wondered if i can have custom instance getters like

```
public function getDefaultCatalogs() {
  return Catalog::where('is_default_catalog', '=', true)->get();
}}
```

within the class itself. Is this possible or are the methods only available to a concrete instance, can i call them like `Catalog::getDefaultCatalogs()` from outside of the class?

Comment: Did you try something like
`Vendor\Webshop\Models\Catalog::getDefaultCatalogs()`

Comment: it wasnt that much about namespacing, more about the static call of the method, "from outside of the class" was a bit misleading, sry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's Eloquent support this kind of behaviour - it's call "Query Scopes" http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

In your model, to this:

```
class Catalog extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeDefault($query)
    {
        return $query->where('is_default_catalog', '=', true);
    }

}
```

Then, you can retrieve record with this call

```
$defaultCatalog = Catalog::default()->get();

// or even order them, if there are more than 1 default catalog. And so on...
$defaultCatalog = Catalog::default()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added the method as a static method to the Eloquent model and it works fine. If anybody has comments on this, let me know.

```
public static function getDefaultCatalog() {
  return Catalog::where('is_default_catalog', '=', true)->firstOrFail();
}}
```

Comment: See my answer. Your solution is fine as well, but with this code you cannot chain another method calls after 'getDefaultCatalog'.